# BIG Query VS Query & search locally VS multiple Queries to Database

Tags: mysql, database, performance

given a Database that looks like this:

*Item*: **item_id**, external_id, title, price, stock, is_active, ...
*subscribers*: **subscriber_id**, description, callback_url, callback_parameters, auth_token
*subscriptions*: **subscriber_id, product_id**

and a Script that do the following:

1. Get list of all items
2. query current item's price
3. If an item update was Significant (price diff is big since last update)
   Invoke this item's Subscriber's callback.

**My question is:  **
what will be better practice?

**Option A:**

- Retrieve list of Items (~10k)
- Retrieve list of Subscribers (~50)
- Retrieve Subscription List (~5k)

and for each significant update, search for subscribers in memory.

pro: small network latency (3 queries)
pro: relatively small network traffic (some redundancy exists)

**Option B:**

- Retrieve list of Items (~10k)

and for each significant change: query the database again for the Subscribers to the specific Item

pro: minimal traffic
con: high network latency (many queries)

**Option C:**

- Query the DB JOINING the Subscriber List

pro: low latency (1 query)
con: high network traffic, (data redundancy - each item will be duplicated for each subscriber)...
this is due to the fact that if an item has 4 subscribers, it's fields will be duplicated 4 times.

Thanks,
Tom W.

Comment: Option D: neither. You obviously want the best of everything in order to gain performance. From what you wrote, I'd say that there's insufficient information to conclude what really is the best approach. For example - what's a significant update? Why would you have to search for anything? What's a subscription list? Why would option C yield high network traffic? Is this an operation that requires only DB updates or are you sending emails or do you have any other external action? There are many more questions I could ask, hence - option D. Feel free to expand the question.

Comment: @N.B. updated the question with schema, what is a significant update, and why i said that one big query will have data redundancy. Hope it's better now.

Comment: How do you determine that the price is changed? You don't have a dedicated pricing table? How do you determine what the stock is? Is the core of your problem the pricing change? If you're looking for the solution given the 3 possible answers, without optional D or E, then the answer Axel posted would be what you need. If you really want this to be efficient, can you expand on my questions?

Comment: 1. I retrieve a Webpage to detect the new price.
2. my price change is not the issue, but the "When" i retrieve the subscibers i need to notify on that change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with that less information I would go for joining items with subscriptions and search for subscribers in memory (half of your A and your C),

Sample:

```
SELECT * from subscriptions, items where product_id = item_id
```

actually, items with no subscriptions can not be "called back". This would only list items and their subscriber ids, of course 4 times if an item is subscribed four times. But, assumed all 50 subscriber subscribe to all products, that would end up in 500K records which isn't an issue for a database.

Programmatically, you would process one record by another and obviously not load all 500K in to mem.

Comment: To clear your POV, you say: query that duplicate the Item fields for each subscriber ?

Comment: No. Will edit Answer

Comment: thanks for the input. BTW: is there DBMS that do not duplicate data on joins like this?

Comment: It's the nature of a join and from a result perspective, there are no duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

None. I would add a column called `old_price` and that would hold the old price. I would write my select this way:

```
select ...
from ...
where abs(price - old_price) > 5
```

This way you get everything you need in a single query. The result will be smaller than every record, so it will not use too much bandwidth. In addition, you will have all the records you are interested in already in the memory, so you can do whatever you need without further ado. You can achieve this with the price of the creation of a new column and by maintaining it on each price update. I believe that is a good deal.

Comment: The new price is a produce of some web query... it is not stored in the DB, yet!

Comment: I believe you should always change the price in the db when it is changed. It is never a good thing to postpone saving your data.

Comment: to be clear you say: 1. query items, 2. update all, 3. query for price diffs. ???

Comment: @TomerW, almost. I am not sure we need the first step. I believe we can do it all with a single stored procedure. Note, that you want to reduce the number of requests to the database server and the number of bytes increasing the server load. Ideally this could be done in a single request. So, you should gather the changes and use them as the input of a store procedure, which, in turn would do everything you need.